# Python: printing a specific word on a specific line

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that will read in a text file and print a specific word number on a specific line given by the user. I am not having any issues with the prompts, I am just having issues getting the specific word. I know that I will be using `readlines()` and `split()`, it's just putting them together that I am having a hard time grasping. A nested for loop? Is one for loop sufficient?

How do I combine printing the line number and word number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started. You stated that you already got the arguments, so you should be able to modify this as you like.

```
with open("inputfile.txt") as myfile:
    for line_no,l in enumerate(myfile.readlines()):
        print "Line number",line_no     
        for word_no,w in enumerate(l.split()):
            print "word number",word_no     
            print "word: ",w
```

If you only need word `w` at line `l` and you can do

```
with open("inputfile.txt") as myfile:
    print myfile.readines()[l].split()[w]
```

Comment: I think it's probably the way I did it but with that I have an error that list indices must be integers, not list. I am using the open(filename) with the close() at the end.

Comment: Where l and w are the user inputs?

Comment: Ah, there we go. Thank you. I appreciate your help.